# Excel: How to check multiple TextBoxes in Userform1 for value and then only pass on value

Tags: excel, textbox, boolean, userform, pass-data

This Userform is used for one specific worksheet called "Job Info".  The Userform has multiple TextBoxes and CommandButtons.  The "Add" button passes data to a specific range on active sheet(always "Job Info").

[https://imgur.com/a/8Rf1oWF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkYH.png)

**Real World Scenario:**

The user opens the Userform to key in data into corresponding TextBoxes (ex. Job Site and Week Ending Date) and then presses the ADD CommandButton to add the new data. Later on that day the user goes back to add or update only one of the TextBoxes(ex. Department) while all other TextBoxes remain empty.  Unfortunately, as the code is written now, the empty TextBoxes pass a blank to "Job Site" and "Week Ending Date".

**Ask**

Would like a solution that checks for value in each TextBox before passing data and if no value is in the TextBox then no value is passed.

```
Private Sub cmdCommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

    ''Here I would like code that checks for value in each TextBox.
    ''If TextBox1 = True then pass value to specified range
    ''If TextBox1 = False then do not pass

    ''Below is current code for passing value when CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("H3") = txtTextBox1.Value
    Range("L2") = txtTextBox2.Value
    Range("K2") = txtTextBox3.Value
    Range("J2") = txtTextBox4.Value
    Range("O2") = txtTextBox5.Value

    '' This code resets TextBoxes to 0 before ending sub

    txtTextBox1.Text = ""
    txtTextBox2.Text = ""
    txtTextBox3.Text = ""
    txtTextBox4.Text = ""
    txtTextBox5.Text = ""
    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve your goal, but here is one that doesn't require me asking any questions.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
End If

End Sub
```

Basically, in the above test code, when `CommandButton2` is clicked, the VBA checks if `TextBox1` on `UserForm1` (which I've referred to as `Me` as my code is written in the UserForm module) does not equal `""` (a blank string).

In other words it's checking to see if the `TextBox` contains at least one character or not. If it does contain at least one character, it writes the `TextBox1.Text` to Cell `A1` on Sheet `Sheet1`. If the `TextBox` is blank, nothing happens.

You can repeat this `If` statement for each `TextBox` you have on your `UserForm` (don't forget to update any control and sheet references for each `If` statement!)